# Using Mobiscroll onSelect function to populate another Mobiscroll

Tags: mobiscroll

I have two Mobiscroll instances one for start time one for end time.

When someone chooses a start time, I want to update the possible end times based on that start time.

I have an ajax call which will give me the correct values for the wheel, but can't get this into the end times mobiscroll.

How do you do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the values (from the ajax call), then you can put it into a select and use the select preset of the mobiscroll.

You can see a [demo here!](http://demo.mobiscroll.com/#demo=dropdown)

**EDIT**

I misunderstood the question, or interpreted a different way. So if the second scroller has to be a datetime picker too then you should initialize it in the first scrollers OnSelect event!

```
$('#startDate').scroller({
     preset: 'date',
     onSelect: function(valueText,inst){
         //get the ajax call done here
         $('#endDate').scroller('destroy').scroller({
            preset: 'date',
            // set other settings like minDate or maxDate for the second scroller
         });
     }
});
```